# unable to use R package threejs and igraph to visualize network

Tags: r, three.js, igraph

I'm using r package igraph and threejs to visualize my network. Here is an example to show the issue I found.

```
# Make a correlation matrix:
mat=cor(t(mtcars[,c(1,3:6)]))
# Keep only high correlations
mat[mat<0.995]=0 
# Make an Igraph object from this matrix:
net=graph_from_adjacency_matrix( mat, weighted=T, mode="undirected", diag=F)
graphjs(net)
```

what I got is a blank picture. 
I also tried to use igraph2graphjs function to convert igraph object to convert it to graphjs friendly object. But it seems like there is no such function from threejs package any more.below is the error message I got.

```
net.js <- threejs::igraph2graphjs(net)
graphjs(net.js)

Error: 'igraph2graphjs' is not an exported object from 'namespace:threejs'
```

A follow-up question is: Is there any other package I can use to make interactive visualization from igraph objects?

Comment: I used your first chunk of code and it looks fine. [link to tinypic](http://i67.tinypic.com/15xqrm1.jpg)

Comment: @link to tinypic      that's weird. I see nothing in my rstudio viewer.  or in my r notebook

Comment: Actually, the `link to tynipic` above is the actual link to the output image that I get for you to check it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

`graphjs` output needs to be rendered in the outside viewer.

If you run the code in the `R` terminal interpreter it works like a charm.

Somehow `RStudio` does not handle it automatically. Try to use the: *Show in new window* option in the `Viewer` panel of the `RStudio`. It opens your graph externaly (e.g. in the web browser).

Comment: True, but it's not very comfortable to the workflow. The answer above should help.

Answer (score 0):

With current version `0.3.1` you can pass the `igraph` object to the `graphjs` function. The issue still persists until you set the vertex attributes.

Setting the vertex attributes `size` and `color` should solve the problem

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)

V(g)$size <- 10
V(g)$color <- 'red'

graphjs(g)
```